# Export oData query server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, odata

Good morning,

I have a Kendo UI data source handling my oData request. The data source is sitting client side and as I filter it , it makes the necessary calls for me and I have some custom markup displaying results. I have a limit of ten records being returned and this is working fine.

On the back end I am using WebAPi 4.0.30506.0   and oData 5.6 (we are stuck with .net 4 ). This is resolving the queries nicely. No problems here.

The problem is that the client now wants to have the filtered data exported server side (data eventually going into a pdf or excel report) , does anybody have any ideas on how to cross the filter settings over to another call.

I have had some success chucking the whole ODataQueryOptions into the cache for each user , but this feels dirty and inefficient.

All ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some serious google bashing I found this nuget package :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToQuerystring/

Examples here : http://linqtoquerystring.net/examples.html

I can now pull the filter value out as a string an reapply as necessary.